# Не вижу изменения после редактирования одного из файлов Django

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

Всем привет!
Может кто сталкивался с таким. Есть Nginx+uwsgi сервер с настроенным сайтом на Django. Этот сайт является одним из вассалов. После внесения изменений в один из py файлов, на стороне сайта изменения не появились.
Из того, что я уже пытался сделать:

- touch файл конфигураций вассала;
- пробовал touch-reload;
- делал reload uwsgi.

Первые два безусловно с параметром master = true.

Какие ещё могут быть варианты? В логах императора я вижу, что:

```
[emperor] reload the uwsgi instance vassal.ini
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Было не совсем очевидно для меня. Но решил вопрос простой перезагрузкой императора. В моём случае это было:

```
/etc/init.d/uwsgi-emperor reload
```